Asymptotic behavior of positive solution to nonlinear scalar field equation
It is well-known that the radial positive solution
$u=u(r)$ to nonlinear scalar field equation  $$-\Delta u+u=u^p\text{ in } ~\mathbb{R}^d, 1<p<\frac{d+2}{d-2}$$ has the following asymptotic behavior:
$$\lim_{r\to+\infty}r^{\frac{d-1}{2}}e^{r}u(r)=C \text{ for some positve constrant C}.$$
In fact, sharper estimates hold:
$$|u(r)-Cr^{-\frac{d-1}{2}}e^{-r}|\lesssim r^{-\frac{d+1}{2}}e^{-r} \text{ as } r\to+\infty$$
and $$\lim_{r\to+\infty} \frac{u'(r)}{u(r)}=-1.$$
Many papers cite these estimates without proof. While it’s easy to see that
$u$ decays exponentially, obtaining the precise asymptotic form requires more care. To make progress,  I set $h=r^{\frac{d-1}{2}}u$, leading to the equation:
$$h''-h=o_{r}(1)h.$$
My initial thought was that any positive solution to
$$h''-h=o_{r}(1)h, ~~\lim_{r\to+\infty} h=0,$$
would exhibit asymptotic behavior similar to $e^{-r}$, However, Iosif Pinelis provided a counterexample, showing that this assumption is too simplistic.
Could anyone provide a detailed proof of the above asymptotic estimates or recommend references that address this analysis rigorously? Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

You need to qualify $g(r)=o_r(1)$. It suffices that $g \in L^1$ at infinity.

@Giorgio Metafune, I believe you're correct, but could you explain the reasoning behind it?

Yes, sure. You can find a proof in the book by Olver "asymptotics and special functions". Check Chapter 6, proof of Theorem 2.1. He uses successive approximations but once a wrote a proof using Gronwalll's lemma. If you are interested I can send the file.

Thanks for your reference!
